# How to place one form just above another in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, notifications, new-window

Im creating a winforms application where I will be notified every now and then of some messages or occurrences.
The notification style that I'm expecting is like that of Gtalk, where if a user sends a message it shows a notification on the bottom right of the screen, and if there is some message from another user at the same time a new notification window will be shown just above the previous one. The new window wont overlap or eclipse the older one.

So far I have achieved few things

Getting the window on the bottom right of the screen which wasnt a big task using this code in the constructor

```
    Rectangle workingArea = Screen.GetWorkingArea(this);
    this.Location = new Point(workingArea.Right - Size.Width, workingArea.Bottom - Size.Height);
```

But now once the form named "Notify" is opened at the bottom right of the screen. When a new notification comes it just overlaps the previous form. Is there anything that I can do for that. Am i missing something really obvious?

Comment: or in windows form you can also use `panel control` instead of another form

Comment: @LifeRunsOnCode any suggestion on how to go about using the panel control for notification

Comment: just post your form's screenshot in which your trying to add `panel`

Comment: i think you can also use `notifyIcon control` which helps to give popup notification in the `taskbar`(in the right corner of the screen)

Comment: Im not trying to add any panel. I want a notification window opening each time when something occurs. I already have a form which opens as a notification window. It works perfectly all i want is that they should not overlap each other instead they should be placed one above the other.

Comment: okay so place a `panel` above your form and make it's size same as the form and make its visibility to `false` in the `form load`, just turn its visibility `true` when you want to show some notification

Comment: Have you tried `NotifyIcon`:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx

Comment: You need to keep a list of the notifications which are being displayed. If another notification occurs, you need to display it vertically higher than the other one. Move it upper the heigth of the notification box

Comment: @AshtonWoods thats where im stuck as of now. I dont know how to dynamically place one window just above the upper height of other window. But for now in my work i have created a timer which closes the notification after 5 seconds. However its not my main requirement.

Comment: I'd simply create a reference variable to the notification which is being displayed. Each time a new notification is needed, the old one is closed. The new one is linked to the reference, and then showed to the screen.
I think this is the basic approach for this kind of situation.

Comment: @AshtonWoods maybe what u say is correct. But I have seen many applications like Facebook Messenger, Gtalk and even Skype. Where if a notification comes, they do tile over one another. I know if it were WPF i would easily go about using StackPanel but in winforms i dont think theres any control. What would be the method to find the exact location where a form ends. Here am talking about the height. If i can find the height of the form that is open, i can easily place the next form just above it.

Comment: I'd then create a list, which contains referenses to the displayed notifications. Each time a notification is to be displayed, it checks the amount of items in the list, and calculates the new location height (list itemcount*notification window height). Also each time a notification closes, you need to remove that one from the list. Additionaly you can relocate the remaining visible notifications, so that the first item of the list is always the lowest one. You'd propably want to make the list public static, so the forms can access and remove themselves from it before closing.

Comment: You may also need to limit the maximum amount of notifications to be displayed at the same time, so they don't fill the whole screen.

Comment: @AshtonWoods that sounds really interesting, however it would be nice if i can get some demo or some source codes.

Answer (score 1):

**This is the parent form with a button, which creates a new notification forms:**

```
public partial class Parent_Form : Form
{
    public static List<Form> activeNotifications = new List<Form>();

    public Parent_Form()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Notification notification = new Notification();
        activeNotifications.Add(notification);
        notification.Show();
    }

    public static void SortNotifications()
    {
        int additionalHeight = 0;
        foreach (Form notification in activeNotifications)
        {
            notification.Location = new Point(0, (0 + additionalHeight));
            additionalHeight += notification.Height;
        }
    }

    public static Point GetLocation()
    {
        int height = 0;
        foreach (Form notification in Parent_Form.activeNotifications) { height += notification.Height; }
        return new Point(0, height);
    }
}
```

The parent form contains a button1, which is used to create new notifications

**This is the notification form example:**

```
public partial class Notification : Form
{
    public Notification()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Location = Parent_Form.GetLocation();
        this.FormClosing += Notification_FormClosing;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { this.Close(); }

    private void Notification_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        Parent_Form.activeNotifications.Remove(this);
        Parent_Form.SortNotifications();
    }
}
```

Notification includes only button1, which is used to close the notification form. Make sure the notification form uses StartPosition "Manual".